How to assign a CRS to a raster in R without error
I've been trying to set the Coordinate Reference System for a raster (.tif) file in my R script, but when I go project my raster I'm getting an error which seems to imply that my object is a data frame, despite the fact that when I check it shows as a RasterLayer. Here's the code I'm using:
raster_template <- raster("C:/Users/OneDrive/GIS_Layers/Extent/new_extent.tif")
target_crs <- CRS(SRS_string = "EPSG:32611")
ext <- extent(raster_template)
max_x <- xmax(ext)
raster_template_proj <- projectRaster(raster_template, crs = target_crs)


and this is the error:
> raster_template_proj <- projectRaster(raster_template, crs = target_crs)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘xmax’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’

I'm using R4.3.3 and I've tried setting the CRS using a different method (+proj=utm +zone=11 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs), I've double checked that my raster_template is indeed a RasterLayer item, I'm quite new to R and I'm not sure where to go from here.

First, I recommend updating your process to terra-1.8-7. Then, from your first raster_template, what does class(raster_template) return. Presumably nothing broken yet. An extent has four values(xmin, xmax, ymin,ymax), where applying xmax across them alll, well, things could go askew. Try without the xmax( and see how things go.

As Chris also stated, I would highly recommend using the terra package over raster. terra is the faster, more modern equivalent of the raster package.  Without having access to your data, it's difficult to say exactly what the issue is.
Based on the error you shared, the extent() function appears to be returning an object of class data.frame which is causing the xmax() function to throw an error because it expects an object of class Extent.
I would attempt the following using the terra package:
library(terra)

raster_template <- terra::rast("C:/Users/OneDrive/GIS_Layers/Extent/new_extent.tif")

ext <- ext(raster_template)
max_x <- xmax(ext)

raster_template <- terra::project(raster_template, "epsg:32611")


If this doesn't work, it would be very helpful if you could share the .tif file you're working with, or reproduce the issue with a public dataset.
terra comes packaged with several sample data sets which can be found within the terra package folder, which is usually:
C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.4\terra\ex\
You can also access these sample data sets with the system.file() function, which will return the path to the specified file.
Example:
system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
